# Как получить список файлов отсутствующих в папке, если есть список всех файлов которые в ней должны быть?

Tags: shell

в папке около миллиона файлов (все одного расширения, названия циферные)

и есть txt файл со списком всех файлов, которые должны быть в этой папке вида:

```
файл.расширение
файл.расширение
файл.расширение
файл.расширение
и тд.
```

как получить такой же список но файлов отсутствующих в папке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, так:

```
$ comm -1 -3 текущий.список.файлов файл.со.списком
```

текущий список файлов можно и не сохранять в файл `текущий.список.файлов`, а передать его по конвейеру:

```
$ ls каталог | comm -1 -3 - файл.со.списком
```

или, если в качестве оболочки используется что-нибудь современное типа *bash* или *zsh*, то воспользоваться конструкцией `<(...)`:

```
$ comm -1 -3 <(ls каталог) файл.со.списком
```

---

пояснения про опции программы `comm`:

- `-1` — убрать из результатов строки, уникальные для первого файла
- `-2` — убрать из результатов строки, уникальные для второго файла
- `-3` — убрать из результатов строки, совпадающие в обоих файлах

подробробнее см. [`man comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html).

Comment: Нюансы: 1) `ls -A`; 2) нужно убедиться, что `файл.со.списком` предварительно отсортирован, и отсортирован по тем же правилам, что и `текущий.список.файлов` или вывод `ls`.

Comment: в конце добавить куда сохранить результат:  > результат.тхт