# Сортировка в bash

Tags: bash, администрирование, скрипт

Приветствую!

Допустим, существует некая директория `/opt/tmp/` с овер 10к файлами чьи имена содержат латиницу, числа и символы точки и дефис но не могут с них начинаться (не являются "скрытыми"), однако стОит подстраховаться на случай если это изменится; и есть некий список с именами файлов `/tmp/list.txt` . Задача: Необходимо из директории удалить всё, что **не** перечислено в `/tmp/list.txt`

Пока решил что буду делать так:

```
cd /opt/tmp/; 
for i in *; do
  grep -q -E '^${i}\$' /tmp/list.txt && continue
  rm -rf "./${i}"
done
```

Был вариант через сортировку:

```
cd /opt/tmp/
ls . > /tmp/her.txt;
sort -u /tmp/list.txt > /tmp/diff.tmp;
sort -u /tmp/her.txt >> /tmp/diff.tmp;
for i in `sort -u /tmp/diff.tmp`; do
  rm -rf "./${i}"
done
```

Возможно существует более правильный или элегантный способ решения задачи?

Comment: А при чём тут сортировка? И кажется, там должны быть не одинарные кавычки, а двойные. И кстати, скрытые файлы не будут удалены, если не включена настройка `dotglob`.

Comment: > А при чём тут сортировка? Первоначальный вариант был через сортировку списков и удаление уникальных файлов. Если Вас что-то не устраивает - Вы можете предложить внести правки через кнопку "править". > И кажется, там должны быть не одинарные кавычки, а двойные. Проверено, работает на bash 4.1.2(2)-release > И кстати, ... "скрытых" файлов там нет, допишу это в условие

Comment: Конечно существует, не заниматься ерундой! `sort` и `uniq` вместе с `xargs` вам в помощь. Делается в одну строку (ну может быть в пару) безо всяких циклов.

Comment: Для затравки `(cat $LIST; find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} \;) | sort | uniq -c`, где `$LIST` — файл со списком, `$DIR` — каталог. Дальше уж сами изголяйтесь, что вы хотите сделать. А вообще луше такие вещи делать на каком-нибудь Python'е.

Comment: вопрос-близнец (лишь условие противоположное): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565326/178576 . это собеседование какое-то или чего-то типа олимпиады/курсов и т.д.?

Comment: ещё один близнец: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/648712/178576

Answer (score 2):

например, можно воспользоваться программой *comm*:

```
$ comm -2 -3 <(ls | sort) <(sort /путь/к/файлу/со/списком)
```

в каталоге, содежащем файлы:

```
$ ls
a  aa  b  bb  c  d
```

и такого файла со списком «допустимых» файлов:

```
$ cat /путь/к/файлу/со/списком
a
b
c
x
```

команда вернёт список файлов, отсутствующих в списке, но присутствующих в текущем каталоге:

```
aa
bb
d
```

дальше можно делать с этим списком всё что необходимо. например, удалить эти файлы, добавив в конце команды: `| xargs rm`

---

пояснения:

- `программа <(команда)` — *process substitution* — выполнить `команду` и использовать результат результат её работы вместо содержимого файла, который ожидает `программа` в качестве аргумента
- `comm -2 -3 файл1 файл2` — опции `-2 -3` означают — убрать из выдачи строки:

  - `-2`: уникальные для `файла2`
  - `-3`: совпадающие в `файле1` и `файле2`
- `команда | sort` — передать то, что `команда` запишет в свой *stdout*, программе *sort* (т.е., отсортировать строки)
- `sort файл` — программа *sort* выдаст в *stdout* отсортированные строки из `файла`

вызов программы *sort* необходим ввиду того, что программа *comm* работает только с отсортированными списками.

Comment: Как насчёт файлов с пробельными символами? (Пробельные -- это также и перевод строки, например)